# $C^\infty$ Urysohn lemma

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $K$ be a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $K$. Show that there exists a smooth, compactly supported function $f\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ supported in $U$ which equals $1$ on $K$.

I want to use the ordinary Urysohn lemma to deduce this. By the ordinary Urysohn lemma (for LCH space), we can find a continuous, compactly supported function $f\in C_c(\mathbf{R}^n)$ with$1_K\leq f\leq 1_U$. Then we can convolve $f$ by a smooth, compactly supported function $g$ to obtain another  smooth, compactly supported function $f'$, but how to choose $g$ such that $f'=f*g$ satisfying $1_K\leq f'\leq 1_U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Choose any $g\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n), 0\le g \le 1,$ with support in $B(0,1),$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}g=1.$ For $a> 0,$ set $g_a(t) = a^{-n}g(t/a).$  Think about

$$f(x) = \int_{\{t:d(t,K)< \delta\}} g_a(x-t)\,dt$$

for small $a,\delta.$

Comment: More details here : https://pillowmath.github.io/Math%20245C/Lec16.pdf

Comment: We need to choose $a=\delta$ here. Then, $f=1$ on $K$ and supported on $2\delta$ neighbourhood of $K.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Do you know a $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty$ function that is $0$ on $[0,1/3]$, $1$ on $[2/3,1]$ and increases smoothly between?  It might be good for composition...