Dense subspace of space of radial in directions functions in $H^1_0(\Omega)$
Consider $B \subset \mathbb{R}^N = \mathbb{R}^{N_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{N_2}$ the unit ball and consider
$$
H^1_{0, x,y}(B) = \{u \in H^1_0(B) : u(x,y) = u(R(s), S(y)), \forall R \in O(N_1), S \in O_2(N_2)\}.
$$
It is very common  in papers the authors just sai that $H^1_{0,x,y}(B) = \overline{C^\infty_{0,x,y}(B)}^{H^1_0(B)}$, without more comments, where
$$
C^\infty_{0,x,y}(B) = \{u \in C^\infty_{0}(B) : u(x_1,y_2) = u(x_2,y_2) \text{ if }|x_1| = |x_2| \text{ and } |y_1| = |y_2|\}.
$$
I am trying to find a precise proof of this. Here there is a discussion for the radial case, but I couldn't adapt the proof for this case.

You can use the very same proof, except that here you should use the Haar measure on $O(N_1)\times O(N_2)$ (which exists as the product of two compact groups is again compact).

In this question and in Dense subspace of space of radial functions in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ the question is about the density of compactly supported smooth function, having a certain symmetry, in the Sobolev space subject to the same symmetry. Let's deal with this question once and for all. Namely, let's answer the slightly more general question:

Let $G\subseteq \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a compact group, $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set which is invariant under $G$ (i.e. for all $R\in G$ holds $R(\Omega)=\Omega$). Then
$$ C_{c,G}^\infty(\Omega) =\{ u\in C_c^\infty(\Omega) \ \vert \ \forall R\in G : u = u\circ R \} $$
is dense in
$$ H_{0,G}^1(\Omega) = \{ u\in H_0^1(\Omega) \ \vert \ \forall R\in G : u = u\circ R \}.$$

Strategy: We know that $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. "Symmetrize" the approximating sequence and check that the symmetrized sequence also converges to our function. The key concept we will use is the so-called Haar measure.
Haar measure: By abstract nonesense (see for example here https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m421/haar.pdf for a neat introduction, or any textbook on Haar measures), every compact topological group $G$ admits a measure $\mu_G$ on the Borel sigma-algebra of $G$ which is invariant with respect to $G$. That means that for every $R\in G$ and every Bore-measurable set $A\subseteq G$ we have
$$ \mu_G(R(A))=\mu_G(A)= \mu_G(\{ aR \ : \ a\in A\},  $$
i.e. the measure is invariant under multiplication by elements in $G$ both from the left and from the right.
How to symmetrize: Now, if we are given $u\in C_{c}^\infty(\Omega)$, how can we produce an element in $C_{c,G}^\infty(\Omega)$? Let's start with an easier example. Let's say we want to produce a function which is invariant under permutation of the coordinates, that is for all permutations $\tau\in S_n$ we have
$$ u(x_{\tau(1)}, \dots, x_{\tau(n)})=u(x_1, \dots, x_n). $$
In linear algebra we have learnt that we can symmetrize in the following way
$$ (\mathrm{Sym}\, u)(x_1, \dots, x_n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} u(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)}). $$
Indeed, if $\tau\in S_n$, then we have
$$ (\mathrm{Sym}\, u)(x_{\tau(1)}, \dots, x_{\tau(n)})= \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} u(x_{\sigma(\tau(1))}, \dots, x_{\sigma(\tau(n))})$$
and if we make the change of variables $\omega = \sigma\circ \tau$, then we see that $\mathrm{Sym}\, u$ is invariant under permutation. Furthermore, if $u$ was symmetric with respect to permutation, then $\mathrm{Sym}\, u = u$ as
$$ (\mathrm{Sym}\, u)(x_1, \dots, x_n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} u(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)}) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} u(x_1, \dots, x_n) = u(x_1, \dots, x_n). $$
Let us now try to do the same thing for a general, finite, group $G$. For the symmetric group we have averaged over all possible permutations (the $1/(n!)$ was important to ensure that functions which were symmetric from the start would remain unchanged). If the group was finite, we could define the symmetrized function as
$$ (\mathrm{Sym_G} u)(x) = \frac{1}{\vert G\vert} \sum_{R\in G} u(Rx) $$
and we would have the same properties as before. Namely, $(\mathrm{Sym_G} u)(Rx)=(\mathrm{Sym_G} u)(x)$ for all $R\in G$ (i.e. it is $G$-invariant) and if $u$ is $G$-invariant, then $\mathrm{Sym_G} u =u$.
If we want to do this for a general compact group, we need to replace the sum by an integral. The overarching theme was that stuff needs to be $G$-invariant and this is exactly what the Haar measure gives us. So, we define
$$ (\mathrm{Sym_G} u)(x)= \int_G u(Rx) \mu_G(dR). $$
As $\mu_G$ is $G$-invariant, we get by the general change of variables formula Is there a change of variables formula for a measure theoretic integral that does not use the Lebesgue measure that
$\mathrm{Sym_G} u$ is $G$-invariant and that $\mathrm{Sym_G} u=u$ if $u$ was $G$-invariant to start with.
The approximating sequence: Let $u\in H_{0,G}^1(\Omega)$. Then in particular we know that $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $u$ is $G$-invariant. As $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ we know that there exists a sequence $(u_m)_{m\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\Vert u-u_m\Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0$. The issue here is of course that the $u_m$ need not be $G$-invariant. Thus, we define
$$ v_m(x) = \int_{G} u_m(R x) \mu_G(dR)  $$
where $\mu_G$ is the Haar measure on $G$. As explained before $v_m$ is $G$-invariant. We now need to check that $v_m\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (i.e. $v_m$ has compact support and $v_m$ is smooth). Firstly, we check that $v_m$ has compact support. For this we define
$$ F_m: G\times \mathrm{supp}(u_m) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, F_m(R,x)=Rx. $$
Clearly, $\mathrm{supp}(v_m) \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(F_m)$. However, because $F_m$ is continuous and $G\times \mathrm{supp}(u_n)$ is compact (as Cartesian product of compact sets is compact) we get that the image of $F_m$ is compact.
Next we check that $v_m$ is smooth. For this it helps to note that by assumption $G\subseteq \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is compact. By compactness of $G$ we know that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for $R=(R_{ij})_{1\leq i,j \leq n} \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ holds $\vert R_{ij}\vert \leq C$. Thus, we get
$$ \Vert \partial_j (u_m \circ R)\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} = \Vert \sum_{1\leq i\leq n} R_{ij} (\partial_i u_m)\circ R \Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq Cn \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \Vert \partial_i u_m \Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}<\infty $$
as $u_m\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. As $v_m$ has compact support, we can differentiate under the integral sign (Differentiation under (measure theoretical) integral sign) and conclude that $v_m$ is differentiable. The very same argument works for higher derivatives. Hence, we get that $v_m\in C_{c,G}^\infty(\Omega)$.
Verifying that the symmetrized sequence approximates $u$: Next we are going to use the fact that $\Vert u_m - u\Vert_{H^1(\Omega)}\rightarrow 0$ to conclude $\Vert v_m-u\Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0$. First we going to compute some gradients. Namely, if $R\in G, g\in C^1(\Omega)$ and $x\in \Omega, v\in \mathbb{R}^N$, then we have
$$ \langle \nabla (g\circ R)(x), v\rangle = D(g\circ R)(x)[v]
= Df(Rx) [Rv] = \langle (\nabla g)(Rx), Rv \rangle
= \langle R^T (\nabla g)(Rx), v \rangle.$$
Hence, we have
$$ \nabla (g\circ R)(x) = R^T (\nabla g)(Rx). $$
With this at hand, we can do the estimates. Using Minkowski's integral inequality and the fact that $\mathrm{Sym_G}u(x)=u(x)$ we get
\begin{align*}
\left( \int_\Omega \vert \nabla(v_m(x)-u(x)) \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2}
&= \left( \int_\Omega \vert \mathrm{Sym_G}\, u_m(x) - \mathrm{Sym_G} \, u(x) \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \\
&=\left( \int_\Omega \vert \int_{G} \nabla[(u_m\circ R)(x)-(u\circ R)(x)] \mu_G(dR) \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq \int_{G} \left( \int_\Omega \vert \nabla [(u_m\circ R)(x)-(u\circ R)(x) \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \mu_G(dR) \\
&=\int_{G} \left( \int_\Omega \vert R^T[(\nabla u_m)(Rx)-(\nabla u)(Rx)] \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \mu_G(dR) \\
&\leq \Vert R^T\Vert_\mathrm{op}\int_{G} \left( \int_\Omega \vert (\nabla u_m)(Rx)-(\nabla u)(Rx) \vert^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \mu_G(dR) \\
&=\Vert R^T\Vert_\mathrm{op} \vert \det(R^{-1})\vert\int_{G} \left( \int_\Omega \vert (\nabla u_m)(y)-(\nabla u)(y) \vert^2 dy \right)^{1/2} \mu_G(dR) \\
&= \Vert R^T\Vert_\mathrm{op} \vert \det(R^{-1})\vert \Vert \nabla u_m - \nabla u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)} \int_{G} \mu_G(dR) \\
&=\Vert R^T\Vert_\mathrm{op} \vert \det(R^{-1})\vert \Vert \nabla u_m - \nabla u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}.
\end{align*}
Note that, as $G$ is compact, we have that
$$ \sup_{S\in G} \Vert S^T\Vert_\mathrm{op},\sup_{S\in G} \vert \det(S)\vert <\infty. $$
Similar computation yields $\Vert v_m - u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \left(\sup_{S\in G} \vert \det(S)\vert\right)\Vert u_m-u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}$. Hence, we get
$$ \Vert v_m-u\Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq \left(\sup_{S\in G} \vert \det(S)\vert\right)\left(1+\sup_{S\in G} \Vert S^T \Vert_\mathrm{op}\right)\Vert u_m - u \Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0. $$
Hence, $u\in \overline{C_{c,G}^\infty(\Omega)}^{H_0^1(\Omega)}$.
The special case at hand: In the previous question Dense subspace of space of radial functions in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ we had $G=O(N)$ which is compact (Orthogonal matrices form a compact set). In this case the group $G$ is given by $G=O(n_1)\times O(n_2)$, which is also compact (as it is a cartesian product of compact groups).
More abstract nonesense: The very same proof would work for any linear Lie group action on $\Omega$ if the Lie group in question is compact.

Very nice answer. Did you take it from any book or paper?

No, it is just the natural thing to do.

This technic is very beautiful. Thank you a lot! I met the Haar measures just now and it is powerful.

I have tried to explain a bit as to why this is really the natural thing to do (starting from symmetrizing as in linear algebra). It is a bit unfortunate that Haar measure are typically not part of the curriculum as they are fairly useful. They are the analog of the uniform distribution, but on a general compact group.
